# override machine.config by web.config HttpRuntime tag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, machine.config

I have problem related about

```
 <httpRuntime  maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"  requestValidationMode="2.0" targetFramework="4.5.1" enableVersionHeader="false"/>
```

I am trying to deploy an MVC5 Website to an IIS Server, but maxQueryStringLength and maxUrlLength does not effect. I suppose that it takes this properties from machine.config. So, how can i force machine.config with web.config for server takes first web.config?